# What is the result of the code?

Tags: c, arrays

please interpret for me about the result that the following code run.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_array_size(int *arr){
    return sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int arr[10];
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n",get_array_size(arr));
    printf("%d\n",arr[10]);
    printf("%d\n",get_array_size(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

which is:

```
10                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2                                                                                                                                                                                                    
0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2
```

Answer (score 1):

All sizes are in bytes.

```
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) = size of array / size of int = 40/4 = 10 

get_array_size(arr) = size of array pointer(which is 4) / size of int = 4/4 = 1. 

arr[10] = the eleventh entry of array(array size=10). (undefined number).
```

Comment: The arr is the entry address of array,why sizeof(arr) is 40?

Comment: sizeof(arr) gives the complete size of array i.e 40 bytes

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-doesn%E2%80%99t-sizeof-a-sizeof-a-0-work-for-an-array-passed-as-a-parameter. Whenever compiler know what arr is actually, it gives the size of whole object, but when arr is passed, it is always decayed into a pointer.

Comment: OK,I have gotten it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_array_size(int *arr){
    return sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int arr[10];
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));//10
    printf("%d\n",get_array_size(arr));//1
    printf("%d\n",arr[10]);//if a[9] adress=x a[10] prints undefined value from x+4 adress
    printf("%d\n",get_array_size(arr));1
    return 0;
}
```

When you call the function local variable `arr` is given priority so 4/4 always gives 1 when called

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
```

sizeof(arr) returns size of array in bytes. Since it is an int array of length 10, "sizeof(arr)" will be "10*sizeof(int)". You are deviding it by sizeof(int). So output will be **10**.

```
printf("%d\n",get_array_size(arr));
```

This is interesting!
You are passing address of "arr" to get_array_size(). In that function first you are getting size of address. The address size depends on the machine you are running, i.e. In 32-bit machine address size will be 4bytes and in 64-bit machine it will be 8bytes. I think you are using 64-bit machine so sizeof(arr) is returning 8. But sizeof(int) is 4bytes. So effectively it is **8/4 = 2**.

```
printf("%d\n",arr[10]);
```

Your array size is 10, so you can access from arr[0] to arr[9]. arr[10] is not part of your array. That address might be used for some other variable. You are just writing whatever present in that address. The output is completely random. I think that address had 0 when you executed the program, so you got the output as **0**.

```
printf("%d\n",get_array_size(arr));
```

This is repeated print (Output is **2**).